# cmd script not exporting to file using >>

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that i'm using to build a json file.

what im doing it creating a number for each record and insert a url with that record and then repeat till all 13797 records are created.

the issue im having is its not creating the completed file.

here is my files.

**hosts.bat**

```
:start
 FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I in (C:\tools\hostslist.txt) do call C:\tools\hosts2.bat %%I
:end
```

**hosts2.bat**

```
set number=0
set link=0
for /f "tokens=1" %%N in (c:\tools\number.txt) do @set /A number=%%N+1
echo %number% > c:\tools\number.txt

echo {"id":%number%,"enabled":true,"flagged":false,"string":"%1%","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.node.GenericRule","blocked":true}, >> c:\tools\UTMHosts.txt
```

**Number.txt** just starts with 1 and counts up

**hostslist.txt** has 13797 urls in it like so (this is just a small snip)

fr.a2dfp.net

m.fr.a2dfp.net

mfr.a2dfp.net

ad.a8.net

asy.a8ww.net

abcstats.com

my issue is the last part of hosts2.bat " >> c:\tools\UTMHosts.txt" isnt creating the txt file and i can not figure out why.

can some one please help
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
"string":"%1" not "string":"%1%"
```

Passing the argument Fred to appendhost means that in appendhost you access the parameter as %1.  It is slightly different to a general env variable which is accessed by %env_var%.

This works:

```
@echo off
set number=0
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (hosts.txt) do call :appendhost %%i
goto :EOF

REM append json fragment to UTMHost.txt
:appendhost
set /a number+=1
echo {"id":%number%,"enabled":true,"flagged":false,"string":"%1","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.node.GenericRule","blocked":true}, >> UTMHosts.txt
```

Comment: that did it arcomber.   thank you so much.   1 little thing broke it ugh  lol

Answer (score 0):

Write `%1` instead of `%1%`.

`%1`is translated to the first parameter, the following `%` starts a new "variable".

Answer (score 0):

This should run faster and do what you need: you need write permissions in `c:\tools` folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set number=0
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a in (C:\tools\hostslist.txt) do (
set /a number+=1
>> c:\tools\UTMHosts.txt echo {"id":!number!,"enabled":true,"flagged":false,"string":"%%a","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.node.GenericRule","blocked":true},
)
pause
```